# Facebook Graph API Call no longer works (because of Facebook Cookies)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, oauth, cross-browser

I have been using the facebook grap to pull photo albums from public "pages" and display the photos, but today it stopped working (and not just on my PC, it has been verified by others)

I've been hitting the graph api without a token and without any SDK, just constructing `graph.facebook.com` links and using the returned json.

At first I thought the problem was occuring only on Chrome but now I'm not so sure. I've confirmed that *spoofing* the user agent has no effect and I've recently discovered that **deleting Facebook.com cookies resolves the problem**.

Now, I can't foribly delete other people's cookies, so I'd love another fix, or at least an explanation.

The graph calls look like `https://graph.facebook.com/{{albumID}}`

*Heres an example:* https://graph.facebook.com/203416696378870

**Error recieved**

```
"error": {
   "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 104
}
```

**With no facebook.com cookies, I get the expected output.**

```
"id": "203416696378870",
"from": {
   "id": "186646504722556",
   "category": "Musician/band",
   ...
```

**Facebook Cookies Before removing**

[image: facebook.com cookies]

I still don't understand why Facebook cookies would suddenly break my code.

I couldn't find any documented change in Facebook's platform updates or Chrome Releases which might explain this behavior.

Of course, I cannot forcibly remove cookies from users of all the sites which use my code, and I am unhappy with how brittle this apparently makes it.

**Does anyone have any additional insight into this problem, and what specifically in the facebook.com cookies messes with the graph api calls?**

**Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?**

Comment: I've got same problem as you getting facebook cookies on chrome. This doesn't happen using firefox. So, seems like related to a chrome update.

Comment: IDK, I've had a tough time pinning it down. I use chrome day-to-day, so none of my other browsers have facebook session cookies or anything (at least not previous to whatever changed), so I cannot do anythign to reproduce it. I do know that there are people out there for who it still isn't working because they have not deleted their cookies. But yes - so far I only have reports from Chrome users.

Comment: I've tested on safari and IE9 too, works in Safari but IE returns a http 400 error.

Comment: @roasted - really? works fine in IE9 for me. You see a 400? With this link: https://graph.facebook.com/203416696378870?

Comment: In fact, IE9 ask me if i wish to download json file. It's look like there is bad request done, asking for a document html page, facebook request respond with a json one.

Comment: Its normal behaviour (I think) for IE9 to prompt for a download. The reponse *is* in JSON, and its up to the browser to decide how to display. Of course, in use, I'm calling and parsing this json with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's weird that facebook is asking the access token, however if you simply need only the pictures from the album, this works for me:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ALBUM_ID/photos?fields=picture&limit=500
```

the fields=picture statement is mandatory for it to work properly.

And you might find this usefull

```
if (empty($_GET['album'])) {

    //get all albums of page
    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/PressPlayPrague/albums?fields=id,link,name,cover_photo&limit=500";
     $albums = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
    $counted = sizeof ($albums->data); // get the number of albums for later use

    //output all albums of given page
    for($c=0; $c<$counted; $c++){
    echo ("<div class='wrapper' <a href='?album=".$albums->data[$c]->id."'><div class='stack'><div style='width:180px; height:120px; display:inline-block; background-image:url(https://graph.facebook.com/".$albums->data[$c]->id."/picture?width=300&height=200); background-repeat:no-repeat;'>  </div></div><div class='caption'>".$albums->data[$c]->name."</div></a></div>");
    };

}else{

    //get the album pictures replace the $_GET[album] with specific ID and remove the     if clause to get only one album
    $pic_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$_GET[album]."/photos?fields=picture&limit=500";
    $pictures = json_decode(file_get_contents($pic_url));
    $countpic= sizeof ($pictures->data); // get the number of pics for later use
    for($p=0; $p<$countpic; $p++){
    echo ("<img style='width:250px; max-height:167px;'src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$pictures->data[$p]->id."/picture' alt='".$pictures->data[$p]->id."'>");

    };
}
?>
```

Comment: do you have a reference for "the fields=picture statement is mandatory for it to work properly"? I've been using it without for quite a long time...

Comment: Open a new anonymous window and go to this:
https://graph.facebook.com/203416696378870/photos?fields=picture
Should retrun the pictures. However if you dont use the statement, the access token is needed to access the resource

Comment: Well, I'm not currently using the `?fields=` parameter, and I am not currently getting the access token error. It worked fine without for over a year, and now works again after deleting Facebook cookies. I'm not at all convinced that your suggested code would avoid whatever problem arose in mine. My (limited and possibly wrong) understanding of the `?fields=` thing was that it allows you to be more specific with what you query so the returned JSON is not bloated.

This *may* be a fix to my problem, but I'd feel much better if I had some explanation of why it occurred in the first place.

Comment: Wierd thing - you are saying that while you are signed in to facebook (cookies are present), you get the error and when you delete the cookies you get the content expected. However when i visit your graph link - the expected data appears and when i visit the link in anonymous window (no cookies, signed out of facebook) it gives me the error.

Unfortunately I can't tell you why my solution is working always and since I guess you are trying to build a public gallery, you should use it ;)

Comment: Sorry I think I explained poorly. I apparently only need to delete the cookies once. I have since logged into FB, used other FB apps, etc.. and it still works (logged in __and__ logged out). I've personally seen this error occur on 3 different machines. I delete the facebook.com cookies, and the error __does not come back__. Once I remove the cookies, no matter what I do, I cannot seem to reproduce on that machine. I suppose I'll change my code to use your method, as it *may* prevent the error - though I haven't confirmed that it works more consistantly (but you have?)

Comment: Oh weird. I just used the anonymous window trick (why didn't I think of that) and the error is back. This leads me to believe that you are, indeed, correct; though the exact mechanism causing my error (and the lack of it) still escapes me.

Comment: Well, in facebook docs there is a statement that you need a generic access token, which might be somehow present in the cookies and as same as the long lived token expires. However since we are using our facebook daily its almost impossible to expire it (if it is there). Juuuust wierd... I've developed the mechanism couple months ago and it's still working. ;) But it might be just a workaround or a bug...

Comment: Thanks David, I really appreciate all the help. I'll award your bounty a bit later in the hopes that more insight will trickle down, but I think this is the winner. Not looking forward to re-factoring all that old code though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you try to retrieve data, but if i use getJSON, it works for me:

```
<a id="facebook-graph-link">TEST FACEBOOK</a>
<script>
 $(function(){
    $( "#facebook-graph-link" ).on( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/203416696378870";
        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: I'm using `$.ajax`, which is essentially longhand for how you're doing it; but this is unrelated to the issue unless you can demonstrate that this code works correctly (on your chrome) while hitting http://graph.facebook.com/203416696378870 directly from the address bar returns the `OAuthException` error.

Comment: Using $.ajax, are you setting datatype json? Just asking in case of... Are your users have to put facebook link directly in the address bar? Sorry for asking these questions but i'm quite confused on what you are trying to do.

Comment: In fact the question should be: is your $ajax request working?

Comment: Yes. It worked everywhere (for over a year) until a day or two ago when it stopped working on my chrome (and a few other peoples' chrome) browser. After deleting cookies from facebook.com on these browsers, it works everywhere once again.

Comment: Perhaps I should note as well, that in addition to hitting the graph api like this with JavaScript and $.ajax, I had an application where I was hitting it with PHP using curl. This also works with the same exceptions as above..

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all Cookies, after that I was not able to call the graph link,

next i go to facebook site, switched to my page account, reloaded the graph link, and it worked

but calling script from my webserver does not work at all

IE10, FF20, latest chrome, all same result

Comment: Hi Yvonne, Thank you for sharing your experiences. Sounds like this is either new info to me, or perhaps your problem is similar but unrelated? In chrome, do you get that Oauth error when clicking this link: https://graph.facebook.com/203416696378870?

Comment: Also, perhaps deleting cookies DID work, but it was a caching problem. On a browser you haven't yet deleted cookies on, can you try to clear you cache before and after deleting the cookies and report back?

Answer (score 0):

Changing IP address finally solved all issues, don't know if cookie deleting was necessary at all, but directly after IP address changed, all worked fine, in all browsers
In one browser I never deleted cookies and also there all working after page reload

Btw. Calling the graph link directly still results in funny things, IE says page not found, safari oath, Firefox shows data, all present website incl album fine, same album I'd like used for direct graph link